# jqueryuihelpers dialog triggerclick event source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jqueryuihelpers (http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/Dialog) for MVC 4. The following code is from the documentation page.

```
<p>@Html.JQueryUI().Button("Click me!", new { id = "triggerButton" })</p>

@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog().AutoOpen(false)
   .TriggerClick("#triggerButton")))
{
    <p>This dialog is opened with a button.</p>
    <p>Please click the X at the top right corner to close it.</p>
}
```

In the above example, the selector of TriggerClick is for just one button and it works fine.

If I have more than 1 buttons, I would like to use the class selector ".button".

```
@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog().AutoOpen(false)
   .TriggerClick(".button")))
{
    <p>This dialog is opened with a button.</p>
    <p>Please click the X at the top right corner to close it.</p>
}
```

In this case, how I can identify which button triggers the click event which in turn opens the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround demonstrated in the shopping cart example on the same page.

```
<div id="cart">
@{Html.RenderPartial("ShoppingCart");}
</div>

@using (Html.JQueryUI().Begin(new Dialog().Title("Remove").AutoOpen(false)
.ConfirmAjax(".removeLink", "Yes", "No",
new AjaxSettings() { Method = HttpVerbs.Post, Success = "removeSuccess", Error = "removeError" })))
{
    <p>Remove the item from your shopping cart?</p>   
}
```

It used the class selector and post back to the server and update the partial page content.

It is not entirely what I want. But it works as alternative.